# What program to use to download videos with Elementary OS

Tags: videos

Fairly straight forward question, what open source, non cloud based programs  are recommended to use with Elementary OS?

Youtube in the next several months is going to remove a vast amount of content and I don't see this content being archived by most people. This is a race against time.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called "Video Downloader", it's pretty simple.
https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.unrud.VideoDownloader

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for downloading videos (including YouTube) I have until now is **Copy Paste Grab**. You can find it into AppCenter in category Internet.

Comment: I've tried Copy Paste Grab, along with Video Downloader and VIDO, but I always get a message saying the video couldn't be found.  I put the same link in 4K Video Downloader and it works fine.  I'd also like to find a good, reliable open source solution but I haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Last few months Copy Paste Grab do not work for me also so I use only the cli youtube-dl

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any particular software but you can use this extension in firefox to download videos from any website including youtube.
***https://www.downloadhelper.net/***

Answer (score 0):

I have used youtube-dl cli and jdownloader and both works great

Answer (score 0):

I use `youtubedl-gui` just copy the name then paste it in appcenter